# loaded "D:\Users\Public\Documents\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin\opencv_world340d.dll" ，can't find or open PDB file

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using opencv in VS to calibrate camera,all Configurations have been done.but the result is wrong.the results are as follows.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLSr1.png)

Comment: Can not find the .pdb file is not that important unless you want to debug inside the dll. This does not effect how your program runs.

Comment: because of this fault,
My program will automatically terminate

Comment: No this problem will not cause your program to terminate. You must have some other bug in your code.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database):

> Program database (PDB) is a proprietary file format (developed by Microsoft) for storing debugging information about a program (or, commonly, program modules such as a DLL or EXE).

In other words, this file is only used when debugging contents of related dll/exe file and has no impact on anything outside of said dll.